# Power Apps - Oracle 12c Server running in Linux

Tags: powerapps

How to connect Oracle Server 12c running in Linux?

If it is possible, please let me know where to install Gateway and Oracle Client?

Also, can you please provide the URL to download the Gateway and Oracle Client for the Linux server?

Answer (score -1):

### Installation

To connect to Oracle database from Power Apps you have to install the following two components on an on-premises Windows machine

1. Microsoft on-premises data gateway (standard) - [download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install#download-and-install-a-standard-gateway)
2. Oracle Data Access Client (ODAC) - [download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html)

### Important

- you don't need to install anything on your Oracle Linux server
- when installing on-premises data gateway, make sure to choose standard, but not personal edition. Personal edition only works for Power BI, but not for Power Apps

### Software requirements

- 64-bit Windows 8.1 or later / Windows Server 2012 R2 or later
- .NET Framework 4.8

### More details

Detailed article on how to connect to Oracle database can be found [here](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connecting-to-oracle-database-from-powerapps-flow-and-logic-apps/)